# colour-coded geo mapping in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to use MATLAB to plot a map of Australia and colour-code different regions (here's an example, this is obviously not Australia!).

[image]

The data I have are latitude and longitude point data. I want to colour-code regions of Australia that fall within a certain latitude of these points.

I'm pretty new to this (not even sure how to use a shapefile) so if there's a tutorial or similar, that would be great!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have access to the [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping/)?

Comment: what do you mean by "within a certain latitude of these points.". How many reference points do you have? What will be the criteria to color code a particular point? If you had only one reference point, then the criteria was pretty clear.

Comment: @MrAzzaman - yes I do!

Comment: @Parag - thanks for your reply, I have about 200 points that fall mostly around the coastal regions of Australia. I want to colour-code different 'regions' (unsure how these are defined, but I'd need them to be smaller than state-level since states are very large) at different latitudes. For example, the 'regions' that have points within -12 to -15 degrees would be yellow.

Comment: Also, the regions that don't contain any points would be white.

Comment: I am not sure about the solution, but it seems you wold need to calculate bearing between your current point and reference points. You can read about distance between two lat-long points and bearing [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: For your regions, you might want to consider the [electoral districts](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1259.0.30.0022006?OpenDocument). You can read these shapefiles into MATLAB using `shaperead`.

Comment: Thanks @MrAzzaman - just downloaded one from [here](http://www.aec.gov.au/Electorates/gis/gis_datadownload.htm) so I now have:
`aussiemap = shaperead('COM20111216_ELB_region.shp');
figure
mapshow(aussiemap);`

Comment: Trying to define colors of the different polygons/regions, my code is wrong but this is what I have so far... `aussie = shaperead('COM20111216_ELB_region.shp');
names = {aussie.ELECT_DIV};
indexConus = 1:numel(aussie);
zone1 = [0 0 0.8008];
mapshow(aussie,'FaceColor', [1 1 1])
hold on
mapshow(aussie(1),'FaceColor', zone1)
xlim([110 155])
ylim([-45 -5])
axis off`